# Java Swing JButton disable not giving disired results

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, swingworker

This is my first time working with Java Swing, so apologies for missing a lot context. This is using Netbeans 7.0.x--business rational. Code is generated using the "Design" feature in Netbeans. Most of the gui code is generated, if not all.

I've tried a few areas of calling `setEnabled` to disable an `upload` button until the file transfer completes. For testing purposes, I added a doubly for-loop to do some floating point arithmetic; I have popup messages before the for loops, and after to mirror some "file upload busy work". None of the places I have called the `setEnabled` function on the button of interest, give the desired result of "greying out" or "disabling" the button--until the `guiController.submitUpload()` call completes inside the body of `swingworker.doInBackground()`. For now I commented out the `done()` functiion.

The desired result: on clicking the `buttonX`, grey out the button or disable it--that is, I shouldn't be able to click on it again--see the first popup in `submitUpload()`, then see the second pop up. The `submitUpload()` function runs it's business logic, and completes. After completing, the `buttonX` should be re-enabled or disable it. Ideally, I'd like to disable AND grey out this button, `buttonX`.

I've tried many of the results in SO, and already read up on documentation:
`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html`
`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html`

Can someone help me out with something I'm missing?

```
=========================
panelFile.java
//private variable
SwingWorker sw = ...;

buttonX.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        //tried disabling here
        //buttonX.setEnabled(false);
        buttonXActionPerformed(evt);
        //renable
    }
}
.
.
.

private void bottonXActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    //also tried disabling here 
    
    sw = new SwingWorker<void, void> () {
         @Override
         public void doInBackground
             {
            try
                {
                if (guiController != null)
                    {
                    guiController.submitUpload();
                    }
                }
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
                }
            sw = null;
            return null;
            }
        /*
        @Override
        public void done()
            {
            buttonX.setEnabled(true);
            }         
         */
        };
    
    sw.execute();
}
=========================
guiController.java


public void submitUpload(){
    //do stuff
   
    //for testing I have pop-ups
    // I should only see this popup once, until the "upload completes"
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getFrame(),
                                  "BEFORE",
                                  "test disable",
                                  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //busy loop here

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getFrame(),
                                  "AFTER",
                                  "test disable",
                                  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


}
```

Comment: `//also tried disabling here` -- and that's a good place to disable the button. Since you're asking about code that is not behaving as expected, it may be best for you to create a [mre] code post with your program. This would not be your entire program, far from it, but a small runnable test program that duplicates the problem for us. The long-running task can be mocked simply with a `Thread.sleep(...)`. Please read the link which will explain what this is and how it can help both you and us.

Comment: One issue is here: `guiController.submitUpload();` this makes Swing calls within the method call, the JOptionPane calls, and by doing this, you are breaking Swing threading rules and can be causing problems with your event thread. Don't do this. Instead use publish and process or use property change listeners to pass information from the background thread to the GUI. Be sure that no Swing GUI code is being called from within the background thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels calling Thread.sleep() seems to freeze the entire gui; right before guiController.submitUpload().

Comment: I was suggesting calling `Thread.sleep(...)` in t he `doInBackground()` method of your [mre], nothing more and nothing less. If it puts your GUI to sleep, then you have unsolved Swing threading issues, possibly coming from code not shown. Again, let's see your [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'll work on that MRE, thank you. I am a bit hesitant on posting something that resembles company code, that's all. I did notice that the "guiController.java" file has a lot of Swing calls. In multiple places, JOptionPane calls are made throughout this "guiController.java" file.  I'm thinking there's threading issues at play here...

Comment: Create dummy code with bland method names that don't come close to resembling protected intellectual property that you are trying to protect.

Comment: Also note that for more complex interactions between the background thread and the GUI, consider use of a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object and property change listeners. This will allow complex notifications to be sent from the the background thread to the GUI, and the notifications will be sent on the Swing event thread, allowing for thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

So yes, call `JButton#setEnabled(false)` where you are calling it, before you execute the SwingWorker, and then re-enable it when the worker is done. This *will* work. If it doesn't work for you, then you have Swing threading problems in code not shown.

Here is my example of a proof-of-concept [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class FooPanel01 extends JPanel {
  private JButton longActionButton = new JButton("Start Long Action");
  private JTextArea output = new JTextArea(15, 40);
  
  public FooPanel01() {
    longActionButton.addActionListener(e -> longActionPerformed());
    JPanel buttoPanel = new JPanel();
    buttoPanel.add(longActionButton);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(buttoPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  private void longActionPerformed() {
    longActionButton.setEnabled(false);
    output.append("Long Action started..." + System.lineSeparator());
    new MyWorker().execute();
  }

  private class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      /****************************************
       * 
       * Do not update the GUI or make Swing calls from here!
       * This includes JOptionPanel static method calls
       * 
       ****************************************/

      // Do some long running task
      // here emulated with Thread.sleep
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
        publish("Processing step " + i);
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
      for (String chunk : chunks) {
        output.append(chunk + System.lineSeparator());
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
      longActionButton.setEnabled(true);
      output.append("Long Action finished..." + System.lineSeparator());
      try {
        // always call get() in the done() method to trap exceptions
        // that may have occurred inside the doInBackground() method
        get();
      } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new FooPanel01());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

For more complex interactions between the background thread and the GUI, consider use of a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object and property change listeners. This will allow complex notifications to be sent from the the background thread to the GUI, and the notifications will be sent on the Swing event thread, allowing for thread safety.